# Handling WebSocket connections in Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, websocket, jasmine, reactjs

I have my `test.login.js`:

```
it('calls login when there\'s a username present', () => {
    React.findDOMNode(LoginElement.refs.username).value = 'foo';
    TestUtils.Simulate.submit(form);
    expect(LoginElement.state.errored).toEqual(false);
});
```

By submitting the form, it calls a login method:

```
login() {
    let typedUsername = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value;
    if (!typedUsername) {
        return this.setState({
            errored: true
        });
    }
    // we don't actually send the request from here, but set the username on the AuthModel and call the `login` method below
    AuthModel.set('username', typedUsername);
    AuthModel.login();
},
```

So I'm trying to test the functionality of `Login.jsx`, not `AuthModel.js`, however by calling `AuthModel.login()`, it sends a message over a WebSocket. However, the issue is that in my actual app, I don't load anything until the WebSocket has connected (I fire an event to then render the React app), however in my Jasmine test, I don't wait for this event, so I receive:

`ERROR: null, DOMException{stack: 'Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.`

And my test fails, which, it shouldn't fail because it's encapsulated functionality does what I want it to. It just errors further up the dependency tree.

What is my best approach for either working around this, or to mitigate the WebSocket trying to connect in my test env? (I'm extremely new to testing, so these concepts are very alien to me right now)

Answer (score 0):

I won't pretend to know a lot about this, but can't you dependency inject AuthModel so how and then mock it in your tests? Sorry this isn't a complete answer it's just what my first instinct would be.

If you need a library to assist this, angular/di (from angular2) is pretty great.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock / stub the server request using Sinon JS. - http://sinonjs.org/

If you just want to know that Auth.login makes a request to the server, use sinon.stub (http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs), e.g.

```
var stub = sinon.stub($, 'ajax');
//Do something that calls $.ajax
//Check stub was called and arguments of first call: 
console.log(stub.called)
console.log(stub.args[0])
stub.restore();
```

If your code requires a response, use sinon's fake server (http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server):

```
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create(),
    myResults = [1, 2, 3];

//Set-up server response with correct selected tags
server.respondWith('POST', url, [200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    JSON.stringify({
        response: myResults
    })
]);

//Do something which posts to the server...
sendToServer('abc').done(function(results) {
    console.log('checking for results ', results);
})

server.restore();
```

You can get a lot more complicated with the server responses - using functions, etc. to handle multiple request types, e.g.

```
function initServer(respondOk) {
    var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

    server.respondWith('POST', /.*\/endpoint\/.*/, function(request) {
        var header = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
        if(!respondOk) {
            var response = JSON.stringify([{
                'error_code': '500',
                'message': 'Internal server error'
            }]);
            request.respond(500, header, response);
        } else {

            var code = 200,
                resources = JSON.parse(request.requestBody),
                result = JSON.stringify({ customer: resources });

            request.respond(code, header, result);
        }
    });

    return server;
});
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! I think I'm still missing a step, in that my Login.jsx doesn't *actually* make the AJAX (in my case, WebSocket) request, but rather it imports AuthModel, and calls AuthModel.login(), which in turns makes a request

Comment: So, essentially, I'm trying to ascertain whether AuthModel.login() was called...not that it then made a WebSocket request, that's not important (for testing Login.jsx)

Comment: Going further with your request - you could stub Auth.login - which intercepts your call at an earlier stage - as your WebSocket infrastructure may not be easy to stub / mock if it throws errors.

Comment: If AuthModel.login is a prototype method, you may have to do:

`sinon.stub(AuthModel.prototype, 'login')`

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. But if I'm right in thinking - I can't get at AuthModel from my test file, no? Within Login.jsx I just import AuthModel from './path/to/auth.js', and I don't export it...so it's not going to be available on the Login.jsx instance...

Comment: Because if in my test file I have:
`import Login from './../../../assets/js/react_components/auth/login.jsx';
import AuthModel from './../../../assets/js/react_components/auth/auth.js';` the Login component is still going to be referencing it's own AuthModel import...no?

Comment: It's okay to import your auth model in your test if you are going to stub it - if it's a "klass" you can manipulate / stub it in your test before Login uses it right?

For example, we do this in some tests because we don't want the server call to happen, we just want to know it happened:

`var stub = sinon.stub(Backbone.Model.prototype, 'fetch');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84698/discussion-between-benhowdle89-and-skila).